# How to retrieve parentaccountid from account using queryexpression and silverlight

Tags: silverlight, dynamics-crm-2011

My query returns account.name, account.account and account.parentaccountid.

I'm using Silverlight and CRM2011.

Now I'm having trouble to find out how to extract value from parentaccountid attribute.

I have silverlightextensionmethods.cs file included in my VS project, and I'm using `GetAttributeValue<Guid>("parentaccountid")` to get the value from `parentaccountid`.

The value returned is empty.

## Has anyone any ideas how to accomplish this?

I can get any other attribute value, but parentaccountid in account and parentcustomerid in contact are making my life very difficult.

Code:
FIRST I CREATE QUERYEXPRESSION:

---

```
string temp="name;accountid;parentaccountid";
string[] fields = temp.Split(';');
 QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression()
 {
           EntityName = entity,
          ColumnSet = new ColumnSet { Columns = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string>(fields) },

         Criteria = new FilterExpression
          {
              FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And,
             Conditions = 
             {
                   new ConditionExpression
                   {
                                AttributeName = parentidfield,
                                Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal,
                                Values = { id }
                   }
              }
           }
 };

 OrganizationRequest req = new OrganizationRequest();
 req.RequestName = "RetrieveMultiple";

 req["Query"] = query;

 service.BeginExecute(req, new AsyncCallback(GetChildren_ExecuteCallBack), service);
```

---

NEXT I TY TO READ VALUES FORM RESPONSE

```
void GetChildren_ExecuteCallBack(IAsyncResult childresult)
        {
            List<TreeRecord> listc = new List<TreeRecord>();
            try
            {
                OrganizationResponse childresponse = ((IOrganizationService)childresult.AsyncState).EndExecute(childresult);
                EntityCollection childresults = (EntityCollection)childresponse["EntityCollection"];

                if (childresults.Entities.Count > 0)
                {
                    TreeConfig sitm = new TreeConfig();
                    string sdisplay = "";
                    string[] fields = "".Split(';');
                    string sid = "";
                    string pid = "";
                    foreach (Entity childentity in childresults.Entities)
                    {
                        foreach (TreeConfig sitem in Configs)
                        {
                            if (sitem.EntityName == childentity.LogicalName)
                            {
                                sitm = sitem;
                            }
                        }

                        TreeRecord childitem = new TreeRecord();
                        string sValue = "";
                        sdisplay = "name;accountid;parentaccountid"; 
                        fields = sdisplay.Split(';');
                        sid =  "accountid";
                        pid = "parentaccountid";

                        int i = sdisplay.Split(';').Length;

                        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                        {
                            try { sValue += childentity.GetAttributeValue<string>(fields[j]) + " "; }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                //s = "sValue haku: " + ex.Message.ToString();
                                //this.ReportMessage(s.ToString());
                            }
                        }
                        childitem.Name = sValue;


                        childitem.EntityName = childentity.LogicalName;
                        childitem.Level = sitm.Level;
                        childitem.ParentEntityName = sitm.EntityName;
                        childitem.Color = sitm.Color;
                        childitem.RecordId = childentity.GetEntityId<Guid>(sid);

                        try { childitem.ParentId = childentity.GetAttributeValue<Guid>(pid); }
                        catch
                        {
                            //sb.AppendLine("guid: parentid tietoa ei löydy");
                            //this.ReportMessage(sb.ToString());
                        }
                        listc.Add(childitem);

                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: First, I create Queryexpression

Comment: You have already mentioned this. Please edit your question and insert the code which you are referring to. Otherwise no one can help you in detail.

Comment: Also please try and avoid sections with all caps. To us its the equivalent of you shouting.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
childentity.GetAttributeValue<Guid>(pid)
```

use

```
childentity.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>(pid)
```